# node.js express cannot upload file through stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, upload, form-data

```js
router.post("/upload", function(req, res, next) {
    var form = new multiparty.Form();
    form.on("part", function(part) {
        if (!part.filename) {
            part.resume();
            return;
        }

        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append("upload", part);
        fd.submit(storageUrl, function(err, res0) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                res.status(500);
            }

            res.end();
        });
    });

    form.parse(req);
});
```

however, I'm getting error on the submit callback.

```
{ [Error: read ECONNRESET] code: 'ECONNRESET', errno: 'ECONNRESET', syscall: 'read' }
```

Anyone know how to fix this please?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```js
router.post("/upload", function(req, res, next) {
    var form = new multiparty.Form();
    form.on("part", function(part) {
        if (!part.filename) {
            part.resume();
            return;
        }

        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append("upload", part, {
            filename: part.filename,
            contentType: part.headers["content-type"],
            knownLength: part.byteCount
        });
        fd.submit(storageUrl, function(err, res0) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                res.status(500);
            }

            res.end();
        });
    });

    form.parse(req);
});
```

Found my own answer.  Missing the file length information.